# gmapsdistance - which API is needed?

Tags: r, google-maps, google-api

I'm trying to use the R package gmapsdistance:

library(gmapsdistance)

```
set.api.key("MY_KEY")
    
results = gmapsdistance(origin = "Washington+DC", 
                        destination = "New+York+City+NY", 
                        mode = "driving")
```

I get the error:

> Error in gmapsdistance(origin = "Washington+DC", destination = "New+York+City+NY",  :
> Google API returned an error: This API project is not authorized to use this API.

I think I'm using my Google Geocode API but I'm not sure what API specifically is needed for this package (geocoding, geolocation, etc?).  The documentation only specifies using a "Google Maps API" which is not entirely helpful.  Where can I go to get the specific API needed to get this package to run?

Comment: I typed "gmapsdistance" in Google and clicked the **first** result and read the **first** sentence of the docs which says: *The function gmapsdistance uses the Google Maps Distance Matrix API to compute the distance(s) and time(s) between two points or two vectors of points.*

Comment: [google api](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/get-api-key#key)